# Display number picker value

Tags: android

I have been trying to display the value from the number picker on a toast message but every time I run, I get `android.widget.NumberPicker{/*some vales in here*/}`. How can I get the selected number on the number picker to show in the toast message?

```
public class NewStudy extends AppCompatActivity {

    final NumberPicker mynp = new NumberPicker(this);
    mynp.setMaxValue(24);
    mynp.setMinValue(1);              

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        Toast.makeText(NewStudy.this,"value: " + mynp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                                 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
   int value = mynp.getValue();
   Toast.makeText(NewStudy.this,"value: " + value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: it finally worked. i can now get my number picker value displayed in my toast message. dope stuff man.